# Xamarin Launcher.CanOpenAsync() not returning correct value on Android 11

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, launcher, android-11

I have two Xamarin apps that I manage. I am trying to open App2 by clicking a button in App1. I have the following code which works on lower versions of Android. On Android 11 however, this code always returns false. Is additional configuration needed for Android 11?

```
//The uri here is correct and App2 is installed on the Android 11 device
var canOpenApp2 = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync("app2url://deep-link"); 
return canOpenApp2
```

On Android 8, 9, and 10 `canOpenApp2` returns `true` but on Android 11 the return value is false. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android 11 developers must specify the apps they plan to open or "deep link" into in the Android Manifest. Adding the following to the AndroidManifest resolved the issue:

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="app2url://deep-link" />
</queries>
```

See this post for more information: [Managing Package Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility)

Comment: What a helpful answer! Thanks, guy!

Comment: No problem guy! It's what I do.

Comment: You can mark this answer(click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer) later which will help more people with same problem:).