# Android/iOS: Launcher.CanOpenAsync always returns false

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui, launcher

I tried using Launcher.CanOpenAsync to see if it can detect gmail and facebook on emulator. It always returns false, even if the apps are installed.

I tried three apps in total, all three installed in emulator:

```
bool supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("lyft://");

bool supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("fb://");

bool supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("gmail-inbox://");
```

Why does it always return false? Any suggestions? I tried on iOS also, and modified the **Info.plist** accordingly but to no avail.

This two lines of code work fine, but i dont want to compose an email, I want to see the inbox, so **mailto** doesnt really help.

```
 await Launcher.OpenAsync("mailto:example@gmail.com");
 await Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.facebook.com/RingotanApp");
```

Comment: What is your Android version? If you are using a later version of Android 11, you can refer to the following links. In the Android, you can refer to the case: [Xamarin Launcher.CanOpenAsync() not returning correct value on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65496969/xamarin-launcher-canopenasync-not-returning-correct-value-on-android-11). In the IOS, you could check it on GitHub page: [Launcher.CanOpenAsync returns false for custom urls on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1350). Hope it could help you.

Comment: I am using version 9 on Android and the iOS I added this line of code and its still not working: 

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>lyft</string>  
    <string>fb</string>
</array>

Comment: You can also refer to another link: [What is the correct format of URI to be used in Launcher.TryOpenAsync()?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd537cab-dbfd-44ac-8437-074096a156a4/what-is-the-correct-format-of-uri-to-be-used-in-launchertryopenasync?forum=xamarinforms)